# Generating data for the Array Adapter

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-arrayadapter

Hi I am new to programming.I am trying to create a android project like contanct list.I am generating data for the adapter class. I am getting IndexOutOfBoundsException. I know this is basic of java but I am unable to figure it out why i am getting this error. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
// How i am setting adapter from activity 

  customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), getDataSetForPojo(), mSectionsForPojo, mMapIndexForPojo);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);
```

// Getting List for the adapter

```
 private ArrayList<Pojo> getDataSetForPojo() {

        List<Pojo> pojoList = genData();

        getListIndexedForPojo(pojoList);

        ArrayList results = new ArrayList<>();
        ElementList obj;
        int section = 0;
        int normal = 0;
        String str;
        String ch;
        int total = pojoList.size() + mSectionsForPojo.length;
        for (int index = 0; index < total; index++) {

            str = pojoList.get(normal).getStr(); //here I am getting error
            ch = str.substring(0, 1);

            if (index == 0 || ch.equals(mSectionsForPojo[section])) {

                obj = new ElementList(ch, true);
                mMapIndexForPojo.put(ch, index);
                if (section < mSectionsForPojo.length - 1) {
                    section++;
                } else {
                    section = 0;
                }
            } else {
                obj = new ElementList(pojoList.get(normal).getStr(), false);
                normal++;
            }

            results.add(index, obj);
        }
        return results;
    }
```

// Generating list for the section

```
public void getListIndexedForPojo(List<Pojo> fruitList) {

    mMapIndexForPojo = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int x = 0; x < fruitList.size(); x++) {
        String str = fruitList.get(x).getStr();
        String ch = str.substring(0, 1);
        ch = ch.toUpperCase(Locale.US);

        // HashMap will prevent duplicates
        mMapIndexForPojo.put(ch, x);
    }

    Set<String> sectionLetters = mMapIndexForPojo.keySet();

    // create a list from the set to sort
    ArrayList<String> sectionList = new ArrayList<>(sectionLetters);

    Collections.sort(sectionList);

    mSectionsForPojo = new String[sectionList.size()];

    sectionList.toArray(mSectionsForPojo);
}
```

// Generating DATA

```
private List<Pojo> genData() {
        List<Pojo> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();

        Pojo pojo;

        pojo = new Pojo();
        pojo.setId(1);
        pojo.setStr("aback");
        pojoList.add(pojo);

      // adding more objects to list.

      return pojoList;
    }
```

Comment: At what line is the IndexOutOfBoundsException being thrown?

Comment: Nobody is going to read through all that code, post only the relevant code to the error.

Comment: @Shn_Android_Dev as seen in my second code snippet I have put a comment there saying "here I am getting error". At that line. while getting data from the list

Comment: @m0skit0 I will try to reduce a code

Comment: Since you're getting IndexOutOfBoundsException, it means that pojoList.size() is less than the variable "normal". Remember that when you call pojoList.get(number) that "get" is 0 based, i.e. the first item in pojoList is retrieved calling pojoList.get(0) and not pojoList(1). You need to investigate why pojoList.size() is less than "normal"- in my experience this is typically due to a human mistake with 0-based indexes.

Comment: I'd also recommend checking that genData() is actually adding the pojo objects to the PojoList. Try checking how large pojoList is at the end of genData() by setting a breakpoint at the line "return pojoList" and make sure its the value you expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your for loop in method "getDataSetForPojo()" is running more than the size of pojoList.

```
 private ArrayList<Pojo> getDataSetForPojo() {
        ...
        List<Pojo> pojoList = genData();
        ...
        // total can have larger value than pojoList.size() if mSectionsForPojo.length isn't zero.
        int total = pojoList.size() + mSectionsForPojo.length;
        for (int index = 0; index < total; index++) {
            str = pojoList.get(normal).getStr(); //here I am getting error
        if (index == 0 || ch.equals(mSectionsForPojo[section])) {

        } else {
            ...
            normal++;
        }

        }
        return results;
    }
```

So it is possible that normal can be incremented more than pojoList size.